# Running Spring Boot app as service using root account

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot Documentation recommends to not manage spring boot service as root user.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service

What are some of the issues I might face if I start / stop my spring boot service as root user?

```
/etc/init.d/myapp start
```

Comment: You could run the application within the init script as a different user account, but there are lots of reasons not to run any non-system application as root.

Answer (score 1):

This is the practice for any non-system process/service. Ask yourself: Why would Spring Boot need to run as root, with unlimited permissions?

Instead create a separate user to run services like this which have the privileges necessary for functionality, and nothing more.

It really is just a matter of security

Answer (score 1):

If you run your spring boot app as root user, and your code or code in any of the libraries you rely on contains a remote code execution vulnerability, the code it remotely executes will be run as root.

Generally speaking, it's good to put a few barriers up between a hacker and root.